# jQuery mobile popup dynamic URL

Tags: jquery-mobile, dynamic, popup, hyperlink

I have problem of dynamically URL in a popup. Here my code:

```
<!-- content -->
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Group 1</li>
        <li data-icon="false"><a href="person.php?id=1#popup-menu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup">List 1a</a></li>
        <li data-icon="false"><a href="person.php?id=2#popup-menu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup">List 1b</a></li>

    <li data-role="list-divider">Group 2</li>
        <li data-icon="false"><a href="person.php?id=3#popup-menu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup">List 2a</a></li>
</ul><!-- /content -->

<!-- popup-menu -->
<div data-role="popup" id="popup-menu">
    <ul data-role="listview" style="min-width:210px;">
        <li data-role="divider">Choose an action</li>
            <li><a href="#">View details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Share</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /popup-menu -->
```

Basically, when I click link on my popup, I'll go to the page where the **callee's url** is.

So, if I click **List 1a** the popup shows, then I click **View details** the page direct me to URL **person.php?id=1**

How can I do that?

I could just create popup divs multiple times according to the number of the list, but I think it's a waste of DOM object (my  last resort if I don't find any elegant solution)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you actually need to pass only an id of a person to your popup you can achieve your goal this way:

**First of all** simplify your listview markup and store an `id` in `data-id` attribute of an anchor of a listview item

```html
<ul data-role="listview" id="list">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Group 1</li>
        <li data-icon="false"><a href="#" data-id="1">List 1a</a></li>
        <li data-icon="false"><a href="#" data-id="2">List 1b</a></li>

    <li data-role="list-divider">Group 2</li>
        <li data-icon="false"><a href="#" data-id="3">List 2a</a></li>
</ul>
```

and add an `id` tag to 'View Details` anchor in your popup for easier access later on

```html
<li><a id="details" href="#">View details</a></li>
```

**Second** on `click()` event store current id to a globally available variable (let's call it `currentId`) and programmatically open the popup.

```js
var currentId = 0;
...
$('#page').on('pageinit', function(){
    $('#list li a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        currentId = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $("#popup-menu").popup("open", {transition:"slideup"} );
    });
});
```

**Third** in `popupbeforeposition` event construct your url and assign it to appropriate anchor.

```js
var baseURL = "person.php?id=";
...
$('#popup-menu').on('popupbeforeposition', function(){
    $("#details").attr("href", baseURL + currentId);
});
```

And finally here is working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/5YKkM/)** for you.

Comment: Good idea by using globally available variable. Although I was expecting a way which doesn't create a jQuery event. Thanks!